# Insert at the end in a linked list in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

For some reason my code is not running insert function. I want to add a node at the end, but because of some error, my second half of the code is not executed which is strange cause compiler doesn't throw any error.

```
//Inserting at the end
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void display(struct Node * head)
{
    int i=1;
    while(head!=NULL){
    printf("Element %d: %d\n",i,head->data);
    i++;
    head=head->next;
    }
}

void insert(struct Node* head,int p)
{
    struct Node *last = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    last->next=NULL;
    last->data=p;
    while (head!=NULL)
    {       
        head=head->next;
    }
    head->next=last;
    printf("%d\t%d",head->data,last->data);  //to check insert function
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *first, *second, *third;
    first = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    first->data = 7;
    first->next = second;

    second->data = 11;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 55;
    third->next = NULL;

    display(first);
    insert(first,24);
    display(first);

    return 0;
}
```

It is not even giving me any garbage value.

Comment: Your `insert` function cannot modify the value of `head` that was passed. That means you will not be able to add a node to an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

When you scan to the end of the list, you're doing this:

```
while (head != NULL)
{       
    head = head->next;
}
```

The problem is that when this loop finishes, `head` is now NULL and then you attempt:

```
head->next = last;  //<-- BOOM!
```

Change the loop to this:

```
while (head->next != NULL)
{       
    head = head->next;
}
```

Now, your loop will finish when the object pointed to by `head` has no `next` pointer.

This does assume that you never pass `NULL` to the `insert` function, but that should be okay because it appears to be a precondition anyway. So just make sure you never do that! Even if you wanted to allow insertion into an empty list, there's currently no way for you to return a new list head.